# Using a hinge to make a monitor work like a laptop's screen

Tags: display, computer-building

I want to use a hinge to make my monitor work like a laptop's screen and cover the keyboard when not in use.

Has anyone here implemented something like that?

On a side note, do you think monitor's rear will collect too much dust in this configuration?

Comment: What is the overall goal, to make a portable desktop? yes, people had done such things before.

Comment: no, not portable desktop. My pal needs her computer setup (meaning mouse, keyboard and monitor) like a laptop.  She doesn't want monitor to take that much vertical space when she's not working (horizontal space is fine... it's just how her room is set up). Plus she likes how there's negligible cleaning to do with laptop because parts are all covered when not working.

Comment: honestly, unless she already owns the components, she'd be better off getting a laptop to start with.   check out of some stuff that ben heck makes or some of the computer modding sites to get some ideas of what can be done.  anything you do is going to have to be custom, there isn't an off the shelf hinged lcd monitor that you can buy.

Comment: @Zach, I understand about it being custom. I was looking for pointers in that direction. I will check out ben hack

Comment: vesa mounts with a very large hinges.

Comment: @progtick: You are only going to damage your monitor by laying it on your keyboard. It will in no way result in a solution that doesn't require any cleaning, also note that a laptop does need cleaning even if not used unless you were to store it in a clean place. You are better off working on that room or to lay your keyboard away than losing time on making something that won't work the way you intended it to...

Comment: she seems adamant. I will show her this post.

Comment: If you have room, you could use one of those articulated arms that connect to the vesa mounts, many of them have enough range that you could tip the screen down, but you'd still be taking up room with the arm assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it may not answer your question well, it seems like a nightmare to accomplish.

I would consider one of the following:

1. Buy a laptop.
2. [Buy a desk built for the solution](http://www.smartdesks.com/down-view-downview-glass-top-school-pc-desks-furniture.asp)..

[image]

I have seen ones with pop out screens, but can't quickly find a link.